# Pandas - similar to Vlookup in excel

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check whether the lookup up value is present in a data frame expect the current row. In below example , the "Key" of current row should check whether the same key is present in below rows, if it's populate the Flag as 'Y' else 'N'

```
import pandas as pd

# Your DataFrame
data = {"Key": ['AB001', 'AB002', 'AB003', 'AB004', 'AB001', 'AB005', 'AB005', 'AB001'],
        "SprintNo": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]}
```

expecting the results as below

```
     Key  SprintNo   Flag
0  AB001         1   Y
1  AB002         1   N
2  AB003         1   N
3  AB004         1   N
4  AB001         2   Y
5  AB005         2   Y
6  AB005         3   N
7  AB001         3   N
```

Comment: `df['Flag'] = np.where(df['Key'].duplicated(keep=False), 'Y', 'N')`

Comment: Also, the last 2 rows should be Y according to the described logic (please clarify otherwise)

Comment: The 6 row should be 'N'  only as the same key is not present below the row #6. that's the logic i want to apply

Comment: I see, this wasn't clear initially, please see a suggestion below

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to compare to all next values, better use pure python and set operations. Here with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to generate the cumulated `set`:

```
from itertools import accumulate, islice

# reverse the Series
S = df.loc[::-1, 'Key']
# create cumulated sets
A = accumulate((set([x]) for x in s), func=lambda a,b: a|b)

# shift and check for membership
# the last item is necessarily N
df.loc[::-1, 'Flag'] = ['N'] + ['Y' if s in a else 'N' for s, a in zip(S[1:], A)]
```

More complex alternative using a rectangular matrix (from [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)) as intermediate and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)+[`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) to compare to the next rows, and [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) to reshape:

```
tmp = pd.crosstab(df.index, df['Key'])
tmp[::-1].shift().cummax()[::-1]

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['Key'])
df['Flag'] = np.where(tmp[::-1].shift().cummax()[::-1]
                      .reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
                      [np.arange(len(tmp)), idx] == 1,
                      'Y', 'N')
```

Output:

```
     Key  SprintNo Flag
0  AB001         1    Y
1  AB002         1    N
2  AB003         1    N
3  AB004         1    N
4  AB001         2    Y
5  AB005         2    Y
6  AB005         3    N
7  AB001         3    N
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a possible solution getting use of duplicates :

```
d = {True: "Y", False:"N"}

def dup_below(g):
    return g.assign(Flag=g["Key"].duplicated(keep="last").map(d))
            
out = df.groupby(df["Key"].sort_values(), group_keys=False).apply(dup_below)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     Key  SprintNo Flag
0  AB001         1    Y
1  AB002         1    N
2  AB003         1    N
3  AB004         1    N
4  AB001         2    Y
5  AB005         2    Y
6  AB005         3    N
7  AB001         3    N
```